# override default import of csv to tibble in newest R studio (R version 3.4.0)

Tags: r, csv, import, tibble

I recently downloaded and installed the latest versions of R/Rstudio, and have noticed that one of the new changes is that when importing csv's, Rstudio now defaults to importing the file as a tibble. While I realize the developers had very good reasons for making this change, I personally find it extremely annoying.

Many of the data files I work with have many (>10) columns, and many of the functions I frequently use to look at the data (i.e. head(), tail(), or even pulling out specific rows from the data such as data[1:5,]) don't function as I would like. In particular, using these functions on a tibble results in the right-most columns not being displayed, which is extremely problematic as I am often most interested in those columns. Even though I have not been working with these new version very long, I am already tired of having to use the View() function every time I want to look at the data or having to convert every imported file using as.data.frame() in order to get my data to display the way I would like. While I realize this probably seems like a fairly minor concern, I personally feel like coding is often frustrating enough that adding in any additional concerns or difficulties only makes coding harder and more time-consuming.

Simply for the sake of maintaining my own sanity, is there anyway to override this default setting and make it so that all of the csv's I import get imported as data frames rather than tibbles?

Comment: Do you generally use the GUI to import data? It may be time to start using code to achieve this, `read.csv()` should still return dataframes.

Comment: when importing, change `read_csv` in code preview to `read.csv`

Answer (score 1):

May be it is not exactly what are you looking for but you can change print method for tibbles so they will be printed as data.frames.

```
library(tibble)
tibble_iris = as.tibble(iris)
head(tibble_iris)
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#         Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

# here we change print method
# it is needed only once at the begining of your script 
print.tbl_df = print.data.frame

# check that new 'print' method will be used
head(tibble_iris)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

@yeedle is correct about how you can change `read_csv` to `read.csv` in the import window, but @Marius has provided the best answer. You've got to get over your frustration with coding because it will save you time in the long run (i.e. having to worry about the new import data default in the GUI).

`read.csv` still works the same even though the GUI changed... You should type:

`read.csv("TAB`

Select the file you'd like to load using the arrow keys and pressing enter, and then type `,TAB` and all of `read.csv`'s options will be displayed.